# Where are core dump files produced by "node --abort-on-uncaught-exception" located?

Tags: node.js, coredump

I just read [this blog post by Netflix](http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/12/debugging-nodejs-in-production.html) - excellent read. I have been playing around a bit with the tools etc. mentioned; especially with generating core dumps on uncaught exceptions by setting the `--abort-on-uncaught-exception` flag. This is also described [here](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/debug) for instance. I think it is working so far with a simple test script (that does nothing but throw an error), as I see this output:

```
Uncaught Error: foo

FROM
run (/tmp/test/index.js:4:9)
wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:265:14)
Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
[1]    18165 illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  node --abort-on-uncaught-exception index.js
```

However, it seems like I am too stupid to locate the actual **core dump file** that this experiment should produce (?).
I looked at `/var/cores/` and `/opt/cores/` which were mentioned somewhere on the web - but these directories don't exist.
a quick `find / -name core -type f` did not yield anything useful either. What am I missing?

EDIT: node version is v0.12.0.

Answer (score 12):

Ah, nevermind. Perfect example of [rubberducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)...
Just figured out that core files are not created if `ulimit -c` is set to `0`, which was the case on my machine (see e.g. [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html)). Adjusting this setting made the `core` file pop up in the working directory.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand I need to set ulimit :)

Answer (score 2):

For me on MacOSX they seem to be deposited in the `/cores` directory e.g. `/cores/core.5748`. As you mentioned you need to run `ulimit -c unlimited` to tell the OS to save core files.

Comment: I had to `chmod 0777 /cores` before my local node.js process could create a core file.